# Is it possible to make a transparent square on a semi-transparent background?

Tags: html, css, transparency

My goal is to achieve something similar to [image: sunset highlighted].
*This example image uses 4 semi-transparent black squares, on the right, left, top and bottom to simulate the effect I'm after*

Using code that looks somewhat like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #0005;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.transparent-box {
  background-color: #fff0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="">
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="transparent-box"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to be able to get this effect with while using oneelement for the background and one element making the "window" so that for example adding rounded courners and similar styling could be done easier.
I've tried playing around with blend modes, but I'm not sure if it doesn't support that or if I've just set it up wrong.

Comment: While editing your question I have noticed your colors have 4 digits. Colors in CSS have usually 3, 6 or 8 digits normally. Details here: [MDN - color in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color).

Comment: Just to be clear - are you basically trying to 'cut a hole' in the foreground (the semi transparent black)? Have you looked at masking?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/css-4-digit-hex-color/ @PeterKrebs

Comment: The 4 digits notation did not work in the snippet @UPinar

Comment: Change opacity of your transparent-box use `background-color: #fff9;` @PeterKrebs it works i think

Comment: Oh okay that's the error in Adne's post. Thanks for the explaination.

Comment: @AHaworth Correct, I have looked a bit into masking and clip-path, but I haven't been able to get the effect I wanted. StackToxs suggestion bellow worked, so I think I'll spare myself going further into that for now. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @PeterKrebs 4 digit colors are shorthand for 8 digits in the same way 3 digit is shorthand for 6 digit. It's #rgba instead of #rrggbbaa. It is supported by the browser, but it looks like stack overflows syntax higlighting doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice trick to get the same effect, is to use a box-shadow on the overlay:

```
.overlay {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 100vmax rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

In this case, 100vmax fills up the whole page.

Comment: I put the shadow on .transparent-box with `overflow: hidden` on .overlay and I got exacly the effect I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- if you change the opacity of your transparent-box (div) and set the
  color to white, you will get the translucent effect that you showed
  in your example link.

//css of transparent-box linked below

```
        .transparent-box {
          background-color: white;
          opacity: 0.6;
          position: left;
          top: 50px;
          left: 50px;
          width: 100px;
          height: 80px;
        }
```

[image: opaque div]

- if you want a shadow around and in the middle the normal picture you
  need to use the shadow box:

```
    .transparent-box {
        opacity: 0.9;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        left: 50px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 80px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 100pc rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    }
```

[image: shadow box picture]

Comment: Not quite. The effect I'm going for is a box that is compleatly transparent that also effects the overlay.

Comment: if you want a shadow around and in the middle the normal picture you need to use the shadow box

Answer (score 1):

you could use two images with the background fixed property to create a similar effect.
Check this fiddle link [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yeshi/3xyh9rLu/43/)

```js
  $(".transparent-box").draggable();
```

```css
.overlay {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #464646fc, #383333ab), url('https://via.placeholder.com/300/0000FF/808080%20?Text=Digital.com');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: relative;
}

.transparent-box {
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/300/0000FF/808080%20?Text=Digital.com');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="transparent-box"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's a very interesting solution, but I think it might be a bit over the top for my purpouses.

Answer (score 0):

Everything was right, except for the colors. I just changed the background and that's it.

I hope that's what you wanted

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
.overlay {
  background-color: #0000003b;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.transparent-box {
  background-color: #ffffff78;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4rem;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="transparent-box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite, this creates a white square with an opacity of 78. I want to create a square that has an opacity oc 0 that also affects the overlay.

Comment: @Ådne-e-moldesæter ok, but if you use the color `# fff0` you will not be able to have the effect you want, the color `# fff0` is transparent meaning that the color is not visible is ZERO

Comment: That is the effect I'm after. The picture in my question doesn't have a white rectangle with a low opacity. It is everywhere other than that rectangle that has a black color with a low opacity. Though I might not have been clear in explaining that.